# Why Ant doesn't copy all files?

Tags: java, ant

Here is a simple `copy` instruction:

```
<project name="Project Name" default="Default target">
    <!-- ... -->

    <copy todir="${tomcat.lib.dir}" verbose="true">
       <fileset dir="." includes="${dir_bdd},${p6spy_properties}" />
    </copy>

    <!-- ... -->    
</project>
```

where

```
${tomcat.lib.dir}=D:/Tomcat/Tomcat7/apache-tomcat-7.0.47-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/lib
${dir_bdd},${p6spy_properties}=../lib/ojdbc-10.2.0.3.jar,../lib/p6spy-2.2.0.jar,../lib/spy.properties
```

None of the files listed in `includes` parameter is copied to `${tomcat.lib.dir}`.

#### File structure

```
/lib
   + ojdbc-10.2.0.3.jar
   + p6spy-2.2.0.jar
   + spy.properties
/scripts
   + build.xml
```

The build script is launched from Eclipse.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with the fact that you're specifying a parent directory with `..` for the `includes` attribute.

From the [Ant documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html):

> Only files found below that base directory are considered. So while a pattern like `../foo.java` is possible, it will not match anything when applied since the base directory's parent is never scanned for files.

This applies in this case since the `includes` attribute holds an implicit PatternSet.

So you will have to change your `${dir_bdd}` and `${p6spy_properties}` properties so that:

```
${dir_bdd},${p6spy_properties}=lib/ojdbc-10.2.0.3.jar,lib/p6spy-2.2.0.jar,lib/spy.properties
```

Then, you can use

```
<copy todir="${tomcat.lib.dir}" verbose="true">
   <fileset dir=".." includes="${dir_bdd},${p6spy_properties}" />
</copy>
```

This way, the root of the fileset will be set to the parent directory and you can select the wanted files below it.

Comment: Is there any alternative without using `fileset`? (+1)

Comment: @Stephan I don't think so, you will always fall under the case of Ant not scanning parent directories. You could use the `<file>` element but then it points to a single file, not a list... I think this whole issue comes down with the fact that your `build.xml` is not at the root of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solve my issue:

```
<copy todir="${tomcat.lib.dir}" verbose="true">
   <fileset dir="${lib_dir}" includes="${dir_bdd},${p6spy_properties}" />
</copy>
```

where

```
${lib_dir}=../lib
${dir_bdd},${p6spy_properties}=ojdbc-10.2.0.3.jar,p6spy-2.2.0.jar,spy.properties
```